# EE & CartThrob: How to pass custom field variables from Cart to Checkout pages

Tags: ee2, cartthrob

In my CartThrob {update_cart_form}, I have a Matrix-populated zip code drop-down field. When a user clicks "Checkout" I want the value of the drop-down menu to pass as a variable to the checkout page and populate the billing zip code field. Is this possible?

EDIT: You can actually view the precursor to this by going here: http://dandelionflowershop.com/index.php/website/cart

Keep in mind that you need $40 in your cart before delivery options become available.

Comment: are you using Profile:Edit by any chance? I achieve this by storing each delivery address as a separate entry in the Profiles channel, then you can use Profile:Edit's `set_active_link` tag to allow the user to change the delivery address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to save some custom data to session using the `custom_data` array like this:

```
<select name="custom_data[whatever]">...</select>
```

Docs: http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags/global_form_settings/index.html#form-fields

The value should then be available in the CT checkout tag like this: `{custom_data:whatever}`

Docs: http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags/global_tag_variables/index.html#custom_datayour_data_field_name

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!